# Errors while cloning Xamarin solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I have cloned Xamarin project from our github repository.

When I build the solution, I get more than 1000 errors.

I am able to create a new Xamarin project, which means all the required packages are installed. 
And no one else in my team get errors when building the solution.

How do I know whats missing then?

Here are few errors out of the lot--

```
The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
The type or namespace name 'DatePicker' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'BindableProperty' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'AppCenter' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'DateChangedEventArgs' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Check for missing dependencies under project -> References. A clean -> rebuild should restore missing nuget packages.

Comment: You may also wish to right click the project within SolutionExplorer and "Restore NuGet Packages"

Comment: Done that, but its still the same. all nuget packages are upto date

Comment: Close your VS. Then open your project folder, delete all of the `bin` and `obj` folders. Then open your VS, rebuild your project.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Done that multiple times, but of no help

Comment: Try to re-install all of your nuget packages, if this issue is disappear.